# What is unclear about this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions, reopen-closed

My question https://stackoverflow.com/q/32014732/2954547 was downvoted several times, then put on hold for being unclear.

The question stated a specific goal, and two unsuccessful solutions I had tried. What was so unclear about it, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Too broad may have been more appropriate, but WTH ...

Comment: You argue that a question stating "I am open to solutions using Python, Bash/Zsh/GNU utilities, and R." should be kept open? You realize if the "unclear" close votes go away, you'll just be smacked with "too broad" instead?

Comment: @Patrice I do realize that, but that's not what I'm asking about here

Comment: I'd say people might consider it unclear *because* it's too broad. The breadth of the question makes it unclear what specific part an answer should focus on.

Comment: It's unclear because, while we do see your *requirements* as well as descriptions of previous attempts to meet them, what we do not see is your current code and a question about issues you are having with it.  Of course, you could just be asking other folks to do this for you, but that's kinda rude.  Perhaps hiring someone to write code for you is an option?

Comment: *What tools or libraries can I use to automate this process?* - Even if it were clear and not too broad, this part makes it a recommendation request, which is also off topic.

Comment: The close reason may not be correct, but the question should still be closed. It is far less work to just leave it closed as is.

Comment: Would [the Software Recommendations StackExchange site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) perhaps be a better home for the original question?

Answer (score 8):

Let's get this out of the way:  **Your question is crystal clear.**  You want a tool to help automate downloading files.

That said, your question is expressly off-topic for Stack Overflow.  We don't support questions looking for tools, libraries, or software recommendations to accomplish a goal.

There's no hope for the question in its current state.  What would make a better question would be if you had authored some code to attempt this but it was broken in an reproducible way, or if you had questions about dealing with burst requests.  Just requesting a tool isn't permitted here.

Answer (score 5):

First off, asking for recommendations for libraries, etc. is off topic.

Second, you ask for a solution in one of a number of languages, which is really broad.  Since there is no code to narrow this down to one language and all you have is a description of some things you have tried, it reads like a "do it for me" request.  Either one of these could get you nailed with "too broad".

Third, your second attempt at a solution sounds promising until you get to the end and it just stops.  Do you need help finding the data source for that dropdown?  Do you need us to come up with a whole new idea?  You haven't specified the next thing you need help figuring out, so we can only guess what you are looking for.  Hence, unclear what you are asking.

I know you specified in bold what you ultimately want, but as stated above, that has problems too.  So you have either asked us to help you with a really big and broad problem or maybe a specific step in getting to that goal (it being unclear what that step is).